# How do you prevent CMake from install()-ing targets from within projects included with add_subdirectory()?

Tags: cmake

My top-level CMake project depends on `some-library`, which I include into my project using

```
add_subdirectory (some-library)
```

and then link against it using

```
target_link_libraries (my-project PRIVATE some-library)
```

I also want to add `install (TARGETS my-rpoject ...)` directives so that my project can be installed to the system via whatever build system is generated (e.g. via `sudo ninja install` if using the `-GNinja` generator).

However, if `some-library` *also* defines some `install (TARGETS some-library ...)` directives, they get lumped in with the installation of my project's targets, which given a few subdirectory dependencies creates a bunch of extra, needless cruft in the system's installation directories which I'd like to avoid.

How can I get CMake to exclude any `install (...)` targets from submodules/dependency projects added with `add_subdirectory ()` and keep only the ones in my top-level project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least as of CMake 3.0, `add_subdirectory ()` has the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` flag that can be added to the end of the call.

```
add_subdirectory (some-library EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

This removes all targets (*including* installation targets) from being evaluated at build time by the default rule, meaning they won't be built unless they are explicitly specified on the command line or are otherwise depended upon by a target that *is* included in the default rule.

Since your top-level project's targets are inherently included in the default rule (unless you create a custom target that also specifies `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, for example), then passing `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` to `add_subdirectory ()` and then linking against the dependency targets will automatically build any dependencies your project needs as you'd expect but **omits install targets** from the default `install` rule.

Therefore, all that remain are your own `install()` targets - none of your subdirectories'.

Comment: Sounds nice, but doesn't work at the moment. The excluded subdir and it's targets will become un-buildable as standalone build targets, because they don't have their own project files. You'll run into `MSBUILD : error MSB1009 Project file does not exist.`. Referencing: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18048

Comment: I don't use VS projects so this wasn't something I would have run into. Sorry :/